# Problem installing MySQL gem on Fedora

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

When I try rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

```
The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2.
Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted! no such file to load -- mysql
```

And when I try to `gem install mysql`

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR: Error installing
mysql: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't find header files for ruby. Gem files will remain installed in
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
```

`$ sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

has also been tried but same error. I'm on a Fedora 10. Help will be much appreciated.Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before you can install the MySQL gem you need the Fedora development packages for both Ruby and MySQL installed. Try:

```
$ sudo yum -y install gcc mysql-devel ruby-devel rubygems
```

and then retry your:

```
$ sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

(also check that /usr/local/mysql/bin is the correct location for mysql_config, it might be /usr/bin instead.)

Comment: I had just about everything exactly the same, except for installing the gcc package.  For whatever reason, that did the trick in my case.

Comment: A year later this answer helped me immensely!

Comment: doesn't always work with all the libraries and the mysql-config passed... :\